# Can a Git commit have multiple tree objects?

Tags: git

Does a commit object always have exactly one tree object?

I can't think of a scenario where it wouldn't be the case but I also can't see any documentation that explicitly states it.

Comment: Why don't you ls-tree a commit and see?

Comment: It's like asking, if a man can have two wives? There's no objective limitation, it's just not always designed to be this way

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov: As someone who lived in Utah for a while, I'll note that actually it's the bordering states that have more of the FLDS families. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does a commit object always have exactly one [top-level] tree object?

Yes.

> I can't think of a scenario where it wouldn't be the case but I also can't see any documentation that explicitly states it.

It's part of the design: without it, `git rev-parse commit^{tree}` would not have an unambiguous result.

One can envision a system *related* to Git in which commits can store multiple trees,<sup>1</sup> but a number of design issues would need to be resolved first.

---

<sup>1</sup>I've thought about this in several contexts, including the "submodules are wrong, subtrees are better but need better support" one.  I have not resolved everything.

Note that the commit object is also required to have exactly one `author` and one `committer` line; `git fsck` will object to the commit if these are malformed.